# Nested Structure of Meteor.user() not getting converted to CSV properly

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, export-to-csv, papaparse

I am try to convert Meteor.user() to Flat CSV File using `harrison:papa-parse`. but the `profile` Object is shown as `[Object object]` in CSV.

I need little guidance where I am getting things wrong?

Below is the **template.js** events code,

```
var data = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
var csv = Papa.unparse(data);
var now = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var blob = new Blob([csv],  {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "User_Report_"+now+".csv");
```

Thanks and respect in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Papa-parse does not support deeply nested structures, as you can see e.g. [here](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/245). You need to write your own function to traverse the object tree.